# Python Pandas comparing datetime values in DataFrame cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, comparison

I run two sets of speed tests and recorded the data into CSV files which I then read back in and converted into DataFrames. When I display the data it looks like this and I have 2 sets of it; one for test#1 and one for test#2

[DataFrame results table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSOh8.png)

What I'd like to do is to compare each cell of test#1 'Time Elapsed' column with corresponding cell of test#2 'Time Elapsed' column and in a new DataFrame display in percentages the change (i.e. +1.05% or -4.72%). I don't know how to access those cells and do any comparisons on them since they are weird data type?

To generate performance tables I wrote the following code:

```
import random
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import logging
import platform, psutil, GPUtil
import csv

#for debugging purposes
logging.basicConfig(filename='stressTest_LOG.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.disable(level=logging.DEBUG)

#enlarge pandas display area
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

def passGen(passLen, randSeed):
    # randSeed = None #None uses time stamp as a value
    # passLen = 15 #password length

    random.seed(a=randSeed, version=2)

    # populate lists with character ranges based of ASCII table
    letters = list(range(65, 91)) + list(range(97, 123))
    symbols = list(range(33, 48))
    numbers = list(range(48, 58))

    passCombined = letters + symbols + numbers
    random.shuffle(passCombined)

    # check if first element is from symbol list and if so replace with a number
    while passCombined[0] > 32 and passCombined[0] < 49:
        # print("First symbol: "+ str(chr(passCombined[0])))
        passCombined[0] = random.randint(48, 58)
        # print("Changed to: "+ str(chr(passCombined[0])))

    finalPassword = passCombined[slice(passLen)]

    return finalPassword


def showPass(password):
    if len(password) > 32:
        print("Invalid password length.\nHas to be less than 32 characters.")
        return -1

    print(''.join(str(chr(e)) for e in password))



####################################### Main #######################################

# Generate CSV file
with open('performanceResults2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:

    #declare columns in CSV file and their order
    fieldnames = ['Action', 'Start Time', 'End Time', 'Time Elapsed', 'OS',
                  'System', 'RAM', 'CPU count', 'CPU freq', 'GPU']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    #gather system information
    info_architecture = platform.architecture()[0]
    info_machine = platform.machine()
    info_node = platform.node()
    info_system = platform.platform()
    info_os = platform.system()

    if info_os == 'Darwin':
        info_os = 'macOS'

    info_release = platform.release()
    info_version = platform.version()
    info_processor = platform.processor()
    info_pythonCompiler = platform.python_compiler()

    # get RAM memory info
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory().total
    mem = str(mem/(1024.**3)) + 'GB'

    # get CPU info
    cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count()
    cpu_freq = psutil.cpu_freq().current
    cpu_freq = round(cpu_freq / 1000, 2)
    cpu_freq = str(cpu_freq) + 'GHz'

    # get GPU info
    # Works only with Nvidia gpus and is based on nvidia-smi command
    gpuinfo = GPUtil.getGPUs()

    if len(gpuinfo) == 0:
        gpuinfo = 'Unsupported GPU model'

    #run random password generator program
    counter = 10000
    testCounter = 0


    #print("Test #1 Start time: " + str(startTime))


    for i in range(0,5):

        startTime = dt.datetime.now()

        while counter > 0:
            pass1 = passGen(30, None)
            #showPass(pass1)
            logging.debug('counter is: ' + str(counter) + ', password: ' + str(pass1))
            counter -= 1

        endTime = dt.datetime.now()
        #print("Test #1 End time  : " + str(endTime))

        timeDelta = endTime - startTime
        #print ("Test #1 Time elapsed: " + str(timeDelta))
        testCounter += 1
        counter = 10000
        testCounterDisplay = 'Test #' + str(testCounter)

        writer.writerow({'Action': testCounterDisplay, 'Start Time': startTime, 'End Time': endTime,
                         'Time Elapsed': timeDelta, 'OS': info_os, 'System': info_system, 'RAM': mem,
                         'CPU count': cpu_count, 'CPU freq': cpu_freq, 'GPU': gpuinfo})

#read back in and display the results
file = pd.read_csv('performanceResults2.csv', delimiter=',')
print(file)
```

And to compare the results I only got this far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#enlarge pandas display area
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

#read in data to compare
test1 = pd.read_csv('performanceResults1.csv', delimiter=',')
test2 = pd.read_csv('performanceResults2.csv', delimiter=',')

#check if dataframes are equal
equality = test1.equals(test2)
print('DataFrame equal: ', equality)


df1_filtered = pd.DataFrame(test1[['Time Elapsed']])
df2_filtered = pd.DataFrame(test2['Time Elapsed'])
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello @michal-ko, please post a sample `df` showing your data and also show the expected output (with explanation of what your would like to do to the original data to get the expected output). This will help posters get a better understanding of the problem better. See this [MCVE guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing you time cell format it hard to help
As I understand you time comes in datetime format in:

```
 dt.datetime.now()
```

if you want to convert to pandas timestamp:

```
 pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime.now())
```

you can run this on your column "Start Time" and "End Time" and reassign them. Check .dtypes() on your DataFrame, it may be "object" then run:

```
DF['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Start Time'])
```

after this dtype should be `datetime64[ns]` which will allow you to make calculations.

Comment: You can see how the dataframe looks like in that link 'DataFrame results table example' I posted in the original post. Before I put them into the dataframe they were all datetime data type. After putting them into data frame they are now pandas.core.frame.DataFrame and I don't know how to convert them back to datetime data type so I can do calculations on them. I used .iloc[] method to isolate one item and check its type